# Interchanging min and max for a continuous function of two variables

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define
$$
M_x:=\max\limits_{0\leq y\leq 1} f(x,y), \qquad m_y:=\min\limits_{0\leq x\leq 1} f(x,y).
$$
Is there a useful set of assumptions under which one can conclude that
$$
\inf\limits_{0\leq x\leq 1}M_x = \sup\limits_{0\leq y\leq 1} m_y ?
$$
As the example $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ shows, this is not true in general. On the other hand, I think (though I haven't checked the details carefully) that this is true provided that for any given $x$, the maximum of $f(x,y)$ is attained at a *unique* $y$, and that for any given $y$, the minimum of $f(x,y)$ is attained at a *unique* $x$. I would be grateful for any reference that discusses this question in detail.

Comment: A possible setting would be  1)  guarantee that both the infsup and the supinf values are critical levels for $f$, and 2) require that $f$ has only one critical point. The fact that $f$ should be defined on the closed square , and not e.g. on $\mathbb R^2$, makes this less natural though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many results of this type, and in general they go under the name of minimax theorems.  Often some sort of convexity / concavity assumption is made, as in [Sion's Minimax Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem).

You are correct in stating that uniqueness of optimizers gives you equality when $f$ is continuous with domain $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.  However, this can fail if the domain of $f$ is different.  For example, let $f$ be the arc length metric on the circle.  Then $M_x = \pi$ for all $x$, $m_y = 0$ for all $y$.  The optima are achieved uniquely at $y = -x$ and $x=y$, respectively, but $\pi = \inf_x M_x \neq \sup_y m_y = 0$.